# Cordova Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'. Failed to read key from keystore

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an application for Android with Cordova 5.1.1.
I want to create a signing APK to upload to Google Play.

I create a release key by running this command on /Applications/rubystack/apache2/htdocs/apps/myapp

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myapp-release-key.keystore -alias my_app -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000
```

Then I create a `release-signing.properties` file on platforms/android. This is the contents in the file.

```
storeFile=/Applications/rubystack/apache2/htdocs/apps/myapp/myapp-release-key.keystore
keyAlias=my_app
keyPassword=mypassword
storePassword=mypassword
```

But, when I tried to compile with command `cordova build android --release`, I got an error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'.
> Failed to read key from keystore
```

Why can it happen and how to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is the way i solved it:

**Steps**

1. With administrator privileges run: keytool -genkey -v -keystore
   c:\my-release-key.keystore -alias appS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
   -validity 10000
2. Answer the questions that will come up and **attention** to the last
   question:

   *"Enter key password for 
           (RETURN if same as keystore password):"*,

   Give a pass which you will use in the next (last) step
3. In the build.json file for field "password" give the password that
   you gave in the previews step (2)